# Firebase Hosting re-writes not working on non-us-central1 region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've deployed a next.js app to Google Cloud and am using Functions and Hosting.

I recently tried to move everything to `northamerica-northeast1` region. I re-deployed all the functions placing `.region("northamerica-northeast1")` at the start of all my Functions as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations). This successfully updated the location of all my functions.

However, I also use a function to serve my next.js app:

```
const server = functions.https
  .onRequest((request, response) => {
    return app.prepare().then(() => handle(request, response));
  });
```

And I re-write all URLs to this function:

```
  "hosting": {
    "target": "webapp",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextjs-server"
      }
    ]
  },
```

This is all standard next.js on Google Cloud stuff and I've been doing it for 2+ years. However, when I moved the function to the new region using this:

```
const server = functions
.region("northamerica-northeast1")
.https
.onRequest((request, response) => {
    return app.prepare().then(() => handle(request, response));
  });
```

It appears the re-write no longer works. The function was updated, but when I visit the site, I get a 404. Then, when I move the function back to the default region (by removing the .region()) it works again fine.

I tried on 3 current projects, same thing.

Finally, I tried creating a brand-new, fresh project and deployed to the `northamerica-northeast` region (as before) and pushed the functions live with the region code in it...so my project never was hosted anywhere except `northamerica-northeast1` and it still failed. However, by removing the region, the re-writes start working fine again and I can see the site. This is even though the entire rest of the site is in the `northamerica-northeast1` region and just this one server function moved to the default region.

I believe this is a bug in rewrites on google cloud? Or is there something I'm missing or some doc somewhere that says re-writes are unavailable in this region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Hosting and Cloud Functions together, the Functions be located in `us-central1`.

> Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

[Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

Comment: Ugh, ok missed that. Thanks for the info